# echo php foreach loop result in 3 column

Tags: php, foreach

I have a foreach loop and my code looks this is:

```
foreach($items as $item){
    echo $item['title'];
}
```

For example I have 15 items in my loop. My loop will output something like this:

```
item 1
item 2
item 3
item 4
item 5
item 6
item 7
item 8
item 9
item 10
item 11
item 12
item 13
item 14 
item 15
```

How can I show my results in 3 columns like the example below in a div or table?

```
    item 1       item 6      item 11
    item 2       item 7      item 12
    item 3       item 8      item 13
    item 4       item 9      item 14
    item 5       item 10     item 15
```

Comment: i don't know how can do it

Answer (score 5):

if you want the results in a table:

```
$i = 0;

echo '    <table>
            <tr>';
foreach($items as $item){
    $i++;
    echo '<td>'.$item['title'].'</td>';

    if($i == 3) { // three items in a row. Edit this to get more or less items on a row
        echo '</tr><tr>';
        $i = 0;
    }
}
echo '    </tr>
        </table>';
```

This code should atleast give you a place to start.

Comment: @user3246727 Yep I just noticed it. And the `<tr></tr>` which should have been `</tr><tr>` which I also fixed

Comment: @user3246727 How can this answer your question? This does not generate the same output as in your example. The output will be `item 1 item 2 item 3` in one line.

Comment: @wumm yes but after the third item it will go to another which is what the OP wants

Comment: @SuperDJ Look at the question closely; do you see it says `item 1 item 6 item 11`? (However I did a minor edit to be able to remove the down vote)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `array_chunk` to split into the number of groups you desire then use twitter bootstrap to place your items into a div like

```
<div class="row">
$all_items = array_chunk($my_array,3);

foreach($all_items as $div_item){
foreach ($div_item as $col_md_4_item){
echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
echo $col_md_4_item;
echo '</div>';
}
}
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this if your PHP version 5.5+

```
$title_array = array_column($items, 'title');
$chunkArr = array_chunk($title_array, count($title_array) / 3);
$count = count(current($chunkArr));
$table = '<table border="1">';
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
    $table .= '<tr>';
    foreach($chunkArr as $val){
        $table .= '<td>'.$val[$i].'</td>';
    }
    $table .= '</tr>';
}
$table .= '</table>';
echo $table;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<style type="text/css">
.item {
    float:left
}
</style>
<?php
$data = array('item 1','item 2','item 3','item 4','item 5','item 6','item 7','item 8','item 9','item 10','item 11','item 12','item 13','item 14 ','item 15',);
$num_item = 5; //we set number of item in each col
$current_col = 0;
$v = '';
foreach ($data as $item) {

    if ($current_col == 0) {
        $v .= '<div class="item">
        <ul>';   
    }
    //$image = preg_replace('/images/','_thumbs/Images',$p->image);
    $v .= ' <li>'.$item.'</li>';
    if ($current_col == $num_item - 1) { // Close the row if $current_col equals to 2 in the example  ($num_cols -1)
        $current_col = 0;
        $v .= '</ul></div>';    
    } else {
        $current_col++;            
    }                
}
$v .= '</div>';
echo $v;
?>
```