# get a 3 column list on laravel filled with array data

Tags: arrays, list, laravel

I have an array. In this array are multiple datas. Like name, created_at, updated_at, id...... and this for about 30 different products.

Now I want to output there names in the blade on 3 columns

Like :

```
product A product F product J
product B product G product K
product C product H product L
product D product I product M
```

( only the names )

I recieve all the names with

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    {{$product->name}}
@endforeach
```

It doesn't matters if it's in unordered list or on a table. I just want to get the product-names on 3 columns and per column about 10 names.

I tried multiple things out but couldn't make it.

Does anybody knows a solution for that?

Comment: do you want to concat the columns ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26076665/echo-php-foreach-loop-result-in-3-column similar question

Comment: I've tried somethings out but get the error that I have a object and the array_column needs a array to work of course..